# Generating simulated data for moderated regression with 5 variables

Tags: regression, interaction

I want to generate some data to test the concept of moderated regression.
For example I would generate five variables.2 Independent,1 dependent and  2 moderated.Then what should be the correlation structure among the five so that when I generate data keeping that thing in my program I got significant moderated regression that is **interaction term of independent variable with moderator variable gets significant**.(all of my variables are continuous).I know moderated variable is categorical but I have seen papers in which it is continuous also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderation just means that the effect of one variable depends on another variable. So it does not have to be categorical. For example, you might suspect that the effect of your education on some labor market outcome declines as you get older.

The details on how to create such an artificial dataset will differ from software package to sofware package, but this is how I would do this in Stata:

```
// make sure I can replicate my example
. set seed 12345

// start with an empty dataset
. clear

// create the 4 independent variables, which are correlated with 
// one another. That is not necessary, but realistic.
. matrix C = ( 1.00, 0.50, 0.25, 0.25 \ ///
>              0.50, 1.00, 0.25, 0.25 \ ///
>              0.25, 0.25, 1.00, 0.10 \ ///
>              0.25, 0.25, 0.10, 1.00 )

. drawnorm x1 x2 x3 x4, n(1000) corr(C)
(obs 1,000)

// create the dependent variable
// here I added the interaction term between x3 and x4
. 
. gen y = .25 + 1*x1 - 2*x2 +.5*x3  -1*x4 + .5*x3*x4 + rnormal(0,5)

// estimate the model on the artificial data
. reg y x1 x2 c.x3##c.x4

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     1,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(5, 994)       =     39.60
       Model |   4619.2547         5   923.85094   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  23191.6696       994  23.3316596   R-squared       =    0.1661
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1619
       Total |  27810.9243       999  27.8387631   Root MSE        =    4.8303

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          x1 |   .8616615   .1784013     4.83   0.000      .511575    1.211748
          x2 |  -2.101443   .1788006   -11.75   0.000    -2.452313   -1.750573
          x3 |   .5841039   .1647756     3.54   0.000      .260756    .9074517
          x4 |  -.8892704   .1626051    -5.47   0.000    -1.208359   -.5701817
             |
   c.x3#c.x4 |   .5606146   .1591019     3.52   0.000     .2484005    .8728287
             |
       _cons |   .0775731   .1541322     0.50   0.615    -.2248887    .3800348
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you very much indeed for your kind help.Please It would be very kind of you if you also tell me another query that I have updated in my question?

Comment: @Maartin Buis I posted another similar type of question please take a look at that in this site "Simulating Moderated Regression Data Set with given correlation structure" your suggestions would be very beneficial for me

Comment: I am not the right person to comment on how to do stuff in R, I am just not familiar enough with it. Otherwise, your question does not seem different enough from this question. So you should be able to apply the tricks in this answer to that question.

Comment: Actually I am not being able to incorporate continuous moderator variable in the model..........I have made the correlation structure but my moderator when Interacted with the Independent variable is not producing significant result.All because of as we know that moderator variable should strengthen or weaken the relationship between independent and dependent also it can change the direction of the relationship without weakening or strengthening the relationship between the independent and dependent variable so moral of the story is ..............thats a bit complicated and tricky.

Comment: Thats why nobody is giving the answer as people have understanding of the continuous moderator variable effect on the relationship between independent and dependent but to implement that in coding or generating that sort of data is a bit tricky and complicated......Had it been the categorical moderator variable then the answer would have been pretty easy..........

Comment: I included a continuous moderator in my example, there was nothing complicated about that. So I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: complication is that I also need to preserve the correlation direction that I have mentioned there

Comment: The correlations between the right-hand-side variables remain unchanged, so that is easy. It is probably possible to derive the raw correlation with the left-hand-side variable, but it is easier to just try out some parameter values till you get the pattern you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38368/discussion-between-naseer-ahmed-and-maarten-buis).